# load 2 different wp-load

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 WordPress installations with different database but in same server. i want to display latest post and image gallery from two my blogs in one external frontpage , i cannot use multisite or  RSS or wp API JSON for display it. so i tried to load 2 wp-load.php  like this

```
function showcontentblog1 () {

require_once("/home/user/public_html/domain/wp-load.php");

$wp_query = new \WP_Query();
    $args=array(
      'tag' => 'video',
      'showposts'=>3,
      'caller_get_posts'=>3
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      //echo '5 recent Posts with tag';
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();



    $pid = get_the_ID();
$link = get_permalink();
    $post = get_post( $pid );
    $content = $post->post_content;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');








foreach($imageTags as $tag) {



echo '<a href=' .'"' .$link .'"' .'/>' .'<img src="' .$tag->getAttribute('src') .'"' .'" alt="'.$post->post_title .'">' .'</a>';


}



      endwhile;
    } //if ($my_query)

}




function showcontentblog2 () {

require_once("/home/user/public_html/domain/domain2/wp-load.php");

$wp_query = new \WP_Query();
    $args=array(
      'tag' => 'gallery',
      'showposts'=>3,
      'caller_get_posts'=>3
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      //echo '5 recent Posts with tag';
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();



    $pid = get_the_ID();
$link = get_permalink();
    $post = get_post( $pid );
    $content = $post->post_content;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');








foreach($imageTags as $tag) {



echo '<a href=' .'"' .$link .'"' .'/>' .'<img src="' .$tag->getAttribute('src') .'"' .'" alt="'.$post->post_title .'">' .'</a>';


}



      endwhile;
    } //if ($my_query)

}

 echo showcontentblog1();

 echo showcontentblog2();
```

but it only load function showcontentblog1 , showcontentblog2 not load

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work because wp-load.php defines the constant ABSPATH as follows:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}
```

As PHP constants cannot change during the execution of the script your second wp-load.php will not use its ABSPATH but the ABSPATH of the first wp-load.php. Since the wp-config.php file that is used is determined by ABSPATH the second wp-load.php will use the wp-config.php of the first wp-load.php.

There are probably many other installation specific constants with this problem. A WordPress installation initially sets up an environment to run in. You are trying to run code first in one environment then in a second environment. I don't think it is possible to do this as the first environment cannot be cleared and the second environment cannot replace the first environment.